# audioread in Matlab 2015b on Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu

I'm trying to read an audio file into Matlab 2015b and when I run the command

```
[data, p.fs] = audioread(filename);
```

I get the following error:

> Error using audioread (line 88)
>   No plugins available for audio file I/O. Ensure that LIBSNDFILE and platform specific libraries are installed correctly.

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: what format is your audio file?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. The format is wav, and the filename is "test.wav"

Comment: hmmm. This should not happen, can you give the exact line you run? i.e. [data, fs] = audioread("test.wav")

Comment: The line is as follow: `function intensity = inten_extract(filename)` `[data, p.fs] = audioread(filename);` `data = mean(data, 2);` I write a function to extract the audio features. It runs without any problems on Windows 10. But it can not run on Ubuntu server 14.04. Does `audioread` relies on some libraries?

Comment: it requires the library for sound files in Matlab - LIBSNDFILE - how did you install your matlab on ubuntu? Do you have the ubuntu version of matlab?

Comment: I have installed the libsndfile library, but nothing changed :-( - The version of matlab is for linux64.

Comment: this has to be a root issue - matlab cannot access the libsndfile directory or something - do all the other functions work? I think your best bet is to ask matlab support

Comment: ok, I'll try other ways. thx :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by checking that the ldd directory loaded (on Ubuntu 16.04)

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
```

Check if the following paths are present in the files:

```
MCR_ROOT/v91/runtime/glnxa64
MCR_ROOT/v91/bin/glnxa64
MCR_ROOT/v91/sys/os/glnxa64
MCR_ROOT/v91/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64
```

If you change anything don't forget to reload the configuration with

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I've tweaked the formatting and english in your answer. You may want to improve this by specifying exactly which files you'd expect to find those paths in. Also, if MCR_ROOT is actually a variable of some kind, you should probably explain what value it ought to take. I don't recall ldconfig files being able to use environment variables in any way.

Comment: I'm happy that you solved your problem. But take care I have had a side effet with the Matlab runtime: the ssh service was down after reloading de ldd configuration or restarting the machine. An alternative is to write a configuration file where you specify directly the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So the libraries are not available for the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It happened that my Debian environment did not have **GStreamer** installed. `audioread` documentation mentioned about it. Please check the link https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html.

After **GStreamer** installation `audioread` function worked as expected.